# Iphone Xib internal structure

Tags: ios, xib

When we see the source code of xib files, There are some key values and keywords. Any one know what is mean of these keyword and how we know which keyword we are use which place. I know the logic what happen inside but don't have sufficient knowledge of keywords(Which are used in xib source code). If any tutorial or documentaion is availabe please post here it will help me.

Thanks

Comment: If designer does not have imac he can write this xml and after that we can integrate that code into our application.

Comment: I think this is a very bad idea. If you can't use IB, then you should just write everything in code. Trying to create an IB file in XML would likely result in many errors.

Comment: I don't think that is a realistic idea. Just an empty nib file in one of my project is 1,500 lines long. Add a few buttons and some image views and you double that. Instead, if the design is relatively simple, the designer could just mock up the screen and give you the resources. Then it is up to you to turn it into a nib.

Comment: Yes, better to get the designer an iMac than to attempt to create your own xib generation tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Xib source code based on parents, child and sibling concept, it means it fully works on tree concept. 

<string key="className">RSViewController</string>
<string key="superclassName">UIViewController</string>
<object class="IBClassDescriptionSource" key="sourceIdentifier">
<string key="majorKey">IBProjectSource</string>
<string key="minorKey">./Classes/RSViewController.h</string>

Class name :- Your current class name.
SuperclassName :- In which class your current class inherited.

Like that all keywords have its own value.
```